# how to use vector to define array of objects of one class into other class in different file

Tags: c++, vector, setter, getter

I want to use array of objects(in data.h file) to my user.h file .i tried this thing as below but my try is not succeed .i want help from you guys .what is wrong in my script. please correct me

// data.h file

```
class data
{
    private:
        int id;
        char name;

    public:
        data();    
        int getid()

            {
                return id;
            }

        void setid(int id)
            {
                id = id;
            }

        char getname()

            {
                return name;
            }

        void setname(char name)
            {
                name=name;
            }
    };
```

//data.cpp file

```
data::data(){

       int xyz;
       char pqr;
       data firstobject;
       firstobject.setid(10);
       xyz=firstobject.getid();
       firstobject.setname(hello);
       pqr=firstname.getname();
       return 0;
   }
```

//user.h file

```
class user
{
    private:


        vector<data> data11;
    public:
        user();

        void add_element(int a)
        {
            data11.push_back(a);
        }

        void get_element()
        {
            for(int x=0; x<data11size(); x++)
            {
                cout<<data11[x]<<" \n";
            };
            cout<<" \n";
        }

};
```

//user.cpp file

```
user::user()
{   user object;
    object.add_element(xyz);
    object.get_element();
}
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your code: in `add_element` your trying to add an `int` to a `vector<data>` which won't work. `data` has a private constructor, so can't be created in the first place. `setid` is assigning the `id` to iteself (you proably meant `this->id = id`), `name` has the same problem. `data::data()` uses a variable called `hello` that isn't defined. etc etc etc

Comment: WE want to hear from you, what's wrong? (Does not compile? Does not run? Doesn't do what's expected?)

Answer (score 0):

This is your `constructor` and defined as `private`? If you dont have any specific reason, move it `public`:

```
data();
```

Same with `user()`

Edit: There are many other things..  explain what problem you are facing exactly

Comment: yes thats my mistake i ll move it public . can you help me to solve my prob ?

Answer (score 0):

Are those the complete files? Of course you need to

```
#include "data.h"
```

in user.h

Comment: yes i have included data.h file .my file is not able to compile

Comment: There are some more issues:  
- A constructor never returns a value, so remove that return 0;  
- You can't allocate another data object within the constructor. That will cause infinite recursion (and I don't even know if it would compile)